# XML Comments not showing on Vb.Net

Tags: vb.net, documentation, comments

I am using something similar to this and it will not display the Summary or Remarks when I am attempting to use the Intellisense for this function?

```
''' <summary>
''' Summary
''' </summary>
''' <param name="param">The Parameter.</param>
''' <remarks> Remarks </remarks>
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 15):

Need to goto Projects -> Project Properties -> Compile and turn on XML Generated File to generate the comments file.. Then build your project and it will work =)

Comment: If you're using a custom library in a project, after turning on the XML option mentioned and rebuilded the library, you also need to remove and add it again from the references of your project. Otherwise it still doesn't show the comments.