# XML Comments <list> not displaying in IntelliSense

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, intellisense, xml-comments

I am trying to get VB.NET XML Comments to work with [IntelliSense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliSense), and maybe it doesn't work the way I think it does.

```
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets or sets the Patient Code.
    ''' <list type="bullet">
    ''' <listheader><description>Validation:</description></listheader>
    ''' <item><description>Field Required</description></item>
    ''' <item><description>Field Max Length: 25</description></item>
    ''' </list>
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <value>The region reference key.</value>
```

This should, when you are typing in a function, display the "Get or sets the Patient Code" then below that, it should display a list of bulleted items with "Validation:" as the header?

[alt text http://www.codejames.com/errored.jpg](http://www.codejames.com/errored.jpg)

Maybe I am doing it wrong, but it doesn't seem to be working correctly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are not doing this incorrectly, it's just simply not supported.  While the HTML markups may appear in the output of some tools, IntelliSense is not one of them.

IntelliSense is a textual display in Visual Studio 2008 and we do not support displaying many / most of the markups as they should appear in an HTML style display.  Instead we tend to strip out the markup tags that are not supported and display the resulting text.

Comment: *This is just sad*.. especially when working with third party libs *THIS* would be a major productivity boost, since one dose not have to lookup the documentation all the time.

Comment: kinda outrageous this is still a "problem" 4 years later.  if Intellisense supports newlines (via `<para>`), at least replace lists with them...

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/1329449/880990. It seems that you have to turn on "XML documentation file" to generate the comments file...

Comment: Stuff like this is exactly why our development team will be transitioning to Rider. Sad. Really not asking a lot here.

Answer (score 0):

You can "fake" it (without the numbers) by surrounding the `<description>` contents with the `<para>` tag -- this will at least show up in Intellisense nicely spaced, but without the appropriate list delimiter (bullet, number).

```
<summary>
Gets or sets the Patient Code.
<list type="bullet">
<listheader><description>Validation:</description></listheader>
<item><description>Field Required</description></item>
<item><description>Field Max Length: 25</description></item>
</list>
</summary>
<value>The region reference key.</value>
```

<s>If you don't care all that much about the generated output, just add your bullet in each line:</s>

```
<item><description><para>* Field Required</para></description></item>
```

See also [`<list>` XML Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms172659)

### Update

Since posting this, VS2012 11.0.60610.01 Update 3 seems to have added formatting support, so you no longer need the `<para>` internal wrapping or adding your own bullets.

Comment: Sorry but it seems that this way is not supported by IntelliSense neither.

Comment: @Son-HuyTRAN since I posted this I no longer need to wrap the inside with `<para>`, but it works in VS2012 11.0.60610.01 Update 3 -- what app are you using?

Comment: I'm using VS2010 10.0.30319.1 RTMRel. I've not tested on VS2012 yet. :-)

Comment: @Son-HuyTRAN : aha, that explains it.

Comment: Seems to have broken again in VS2012 11.0.61030.00 Update 4

Comment: Can confirm that it does not format in VS 2015 without using the internal `<para>` wrapper. Yet another disappointment from Microsoft.