# Summary is not showing in the assembly if it is added as a reference

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, xml-documentation

I've created a 'Class Library' in C#, which has many functions with summary (XML documentation comments).

For example

```
///<summary>
///Adds the two numbres
///</summary>
public void Add()
{
    //statements
}
```

if i use the function in the same namespace , its showing the summary, but if i added it as reference in some ohter workspace(solution) its not showing the summary.

How to make it visible i other solutions if a added it as a reference, and wat may be the reason for this?

Comment: [Try this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329338/xml-comments-not-showing-on-vb-net)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You need to generate XML documentation for the assembly (a file named myassembly.xml) and copy it alongside your .dll where it's referenced by your other projects. See [this page in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4sa0ak0.aspx) for instructions.

Comment: How come the .net framework assemblies Provide Intellisense then? also other 3rd party controls like telerik and free Ajax Control Toolkit

Comment: I had to restart VS for this change to apply.

Answer (score 70):

1. Go to the solution explorer of your source code. Right click on the **project name** and go the **properties**.
2. go to the **Build** tab if you are using c# and select the check box **Xml documentation file**.
3. When you build your source code the Xml file will be generated in the location where your dll is present.
4. while copy your dll to the solution copy the xml file and paste into the bin of your destination solution.

Comment: Just as a reminder, there are separate settings for Debug and Release! You can check/uncheck "Xml documentation file" for both of them separately in your project settings.

Answer (score 5):

1. Go to the **solution explorer** of your source code. Right click on the project name and go the **properties**.
2. Go to the **Build** tab if you are using c# and select the check box **documentation file**.
3. XML file will be generated within your DLL.
   3-1. You can define optional path for your generated XML.
4. Copy XML file with your DLL into folder that you are using DLL.

First and second step copied from @PushParaj's answer. Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

When you compile  classes that have xml comment,
normally a .xml file is created. (check the options in Visual Studio)

When you add a reference to such an assembly, make sure the XML file is present.
The documentation is not contained within the assembly but within the xml file.