# XML comments from C# project are not shown in VB

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net, visual-studio-2013, comments

I created a solution with two projects. One is written in c#, the other one is written in VB and has a reference to the c# project.

When i call a method from the c# project in my VB code, the XML comments are not shown. However if i call the method from the c# project the XML comments show up properly. I even created a third project (c# as well) and added a reference to my first c# project. The XML comments show up here as well.

What do i need to do to see my XML comments within the entire solution? Why are the comments not shown with my current setup?

Comment: Perhaps these will help: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632942/how-do-you-get-xml-comments-to-appear-in-a-different-project-dll), and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476915/summary-is-not-showing-in-the-assembly-if-it-is-added-as-a-reference).

Comment: thank you, this helped me find this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4sa0ak0.aspx - however if i set the checkbox to "generate a XML documentation file", it still is not found automatically in my VB project. Do i need to somehow add a reference to the .xml file as well?

Comment: Restarting VS13 fixed the issue. "Generate a XML documentation file" is all it takes. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Justin Ryan i noticed that i was missing an .xml documentation file.

Follow the instructions on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4sa0ak0.aspx if you run into the same problem (this is also applicable if you generate a .dll file and need to include .xml comments).