# Why I can't see xml comments from external library?

Tags: c#, documentation, xml-comments

Is it normal I can't see xml comments from external libraries?
For example I have an external library with xml comments on methods. After making a reference to this library I was hoping that xml comments appears when I make usage of the external library; But nothing appear in the tooltip :

[image: screenshot]

Maybe I have to do something special when I make the build of the lib.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482609/c-sharp-class-library-method-summaries-not-showing-in-intellisense-of-vb-net-pro or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329338/xml-comments-not-showing-on-vb-net

Comment: Did you compile the library code with the option to generate the XML file turned on?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First you need to enabled "XML File Documentation" generation. You can find it in the Settings of the Project under the section Build.

Then will the compiler generate an XML File containing your documentation of the assembly on build.

If you reference the assembly in another project and you want to see the documentation of types, methods, etc. in IntelliSense you need to store the xml documentation file in the same folder, where the referenced assembly is stored.